# Selecting latest date by expression

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, expression

I am trying to select the latest date by expression in QGIS.

I tried to use this code `"Date"= maximum("Date")`. But nothing was selected.

I wonder what is the right expression code to select the latest date in general?

The date is formatted as follows for example: `28-4-2018`

And could I select the latest date for a specific `"ID"`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, that this is not a "date" format. QGIS uses the international date format which looks like this: `yyyy-MM-dd`. See [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Luckily you can re-format your string to a date using QGIS expressions and then select the maximum of it. Use this expression:

```py
maximum(
    to_date(
        to_string(
            array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),2) 
            || '-' || 
            if(length(to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),1)))=1,'0' || to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),1)),to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),1)))
            || '-' || 
            if(length(to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),0)))=1,'0' || to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),0)),to_string(array_get(string_to_array( "date", '-'),0))) 
        )
    )
)
```

This expression generates an array of your string separated by `-` signs. (Thanks to @PieterB for pointing out [this elegant solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/336746/107424)). So `array 0` represents the day, `array 1` the month and `array 2` the year. If string length of day or month is only 1, then it adds a leading `0` to it. The string then gets concatenated and transformed into QGIS date format. Now the maximum can be selected.

Unfortunately you can not combine `maximum()` function with `AND` operator because `maximum()` can not be converted to boolean. So `maximum() AND "id" = 1` wont work.

Comment: Nice solution. But I think it is only valid for QGIS 3.x, is not it?

Comment: Yes it only works in QGIS 3. But since now QGIS 3.4 replaced 2.18 as LTR this should be ok. In QGIS 2.18 the extraction of day, month and year needs to be done another way.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all an elegant solution but it works. For those who are still glued to QGIS 2.18.

Let's assume there is a vector layer with the following attribute table.

[image: input]

So, the main idea is to select the latest date by expression. It could be feasible by means of the expression that must be pasted in `'Select feature using an expression'`. And then press <kbd>Select</kbd>.

```py
concat(right("Date",4),'-', regexp_replace(regexp_replace("Date",
       concat(regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date", 
       right("Date",5),''),'(\\d+)'),'-'),''), right("Date",5),''), '-', 
       regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date", right("Date",5),''), 
       '(\\d+)'))
=
maximum(concat(right("Date",4),'-', 
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace("Date", 
       concat(regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date",right("Date",5),''),  
       '(\\d+)'),'-'),''), right("Date",5),''), '-', 
       regexp_substr(regexp_replace( "Date",right("Date",5),''), 
       '(\\d+)')))
```

As a result, it will select the required feature, see image below

[image: output1]

---

It will work vice verse as well. For selecting the oldest date use this expression

```py
concat(right("Date",4),'-', regexp_replace(regexp_replace("Date",
       concat(regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date", 
       right("Date",5),''),'(\\d+)'),'-'),''), right("Date",5),''), '-', 
       regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date", right("Date",5),''), 
       '(\\d+)'))
=
minimum(concat(right("Date",4),'-', 
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace("Date", 
       concat(regexp_substr(regexp_replace("Date",right("Date",5),''),  
       '(\\d+)'),'-'),''), right("Date",5),''), '-', 
       regexp_substr(regexp_replace( "Date",right("Date",5),''), 
       '(\\d+)')))
```

As a result, it will select the required feature, see image below

[image: output2]